# Reading file from a directory in Python

Tags: python

I have a folder containing files on my desktop, and I'm trying to write a script that will read each of the file, replace the spaces with commas, and then return each file as a CSV file.

Here is my code but it is not working:

```
import os
import re
import csv

path = 'C:\Users\Kenny\Desktop\TTUM'
listing = os.listdir(path)
for infile in listing:
    dir_item_path = os.path.join(path, infile)
    fh = open(dir_item_path,'r')
    for line in fh.readlines():
         space_remove = re.sub(r"\s+",",",line.rstrip())
         split_Line = space_remove.split(" ")
         Fname = infile 
         Lname = Fname.split('.')[0]
         name = Lname + ".csv"
         process_file = open(name,"wb")
         newfile = csv.writer(process_file)
         newfile.writerow(split_Line)
         process_file.close()
```

Comment: Hello and welcome, please be precise in your question. What is the issue?

Comment: `path = r'C:\Users\Kenny\Desktop\TTUM'`

Comment: *"it is not working"* is not a helpful problem statement. Errors (provide full traceback)? Unexpected outputs (provide inputs and expected and actual outputs)? And your deadline is nobody else's problem - see e.g. [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/6506/248731).

Comment: it's working now, thanks rje, and others, that was kind of u. I saw my mistake. Thanks alot

Comment: @Emack333: the below answer seems to have resolved your question. Would you consider accepting it? To accept an answer, click the tick mark to the left of it, so that it turns green. This is how we thank helpful people here on _Stack Overflow_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are re-opening the file, writing a line, and closing every time. This will truncate the file and just write the single line. Try opening before the for loop (which you are already doing with the input file), and closing when everything is done.

```
path = 'C:\Users\Kenny\Desktop\TTUM'
listing = os.listdir(path)

for infile in listing:
    dir_item_path = os.path.join(path, infile)
    fh = open(dir_item_path,'r')
    Fname = infile 
    Lname = Fname.split('.')[0]
    name = Lname + ".csv"
    process_file = open(name,"wb")
    newfile = csv.writer(process_file)
    for line in fh.readlines():
         space_remove = re.sub(r"\s+",",",line.rstrip())
         split_Line = space_remove.split(" ")
         newfile.writerow(split_Line)
    process_file.close()
```

Of course there may be wrong a lot more with your script, but for that you need to explain exactly what the problem is.

Comment: also worth noting, the for loop is opening a file with the handle fh each time, but never closes it.